# How to create a query in Mongoose/Mongodb to obtain this json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to obtain an object like this from my mongodb, counting the OS per month:

`{January: {Android: 30, iOS: 10, winPhone: 5}, February: {Android: 4, iOS: 40}, etc}.`

And here is my mongoose schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  date: {type: Date,  default: Date.now},
  os: String
});
```

Can give me someone an idea? Is there a way to create a single query to return me the entire object or should I build it piece by piece, unifying multiple queries?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at using an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) for that.

Comment: This is definitely not a aggregation pipeline use case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to project **values as keys** in the output, you can't achieve this using the aggregation pipeline. **None** of the pipeline operators accept values as keys. You need to write map reduce functions. The `map` function that groups the records based on the year. So the `year` is `emitted` as the key. The value being each `os` name and 'month' in which it was sold.

The `map` function:

```
var map = function(){
emit(this.date.getFullYear(),
    {"month":this.date.getMonth(),"os":this.os});
}
```

The `reduce` function for each group now aggregates the `count` of different `types` of `os` sold in a month for that year.

```
var reduce = function(id,osArr){
var result = {};
var osCount = {};
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
for(var i=0;i<osArr.length;i++)
{
    var mon = monthNames[(osArr[i].month)-1];
    if(!osCount.hasOwnProperty(mon))
    {
        osCount[mon] = {};
    }
    if(osCount[mon].hasOwnProperty(osArr[i].os))
    {
        osCount[mon][osArr[i].os]++;
    }
    else
    {
        osCount[mon][osArr[i].os] = 1;
    }
}
result[id] = osCount;
return result;
}
```

Call the map reduce function on the collection and dump it to a new collection named 'temp'.

```
var o = {};
o.map = map;
o.reduce = reduce;
o.out = { replace: 'temp' }
o.verbose = true;

ModelName.mapReduce(o, function (err, results) {
console.log(results)
})
```

This yields the following Sample results:

```
> db.temp.find({},{"value":1,"_id":0})
{ "value" : { "2013" : { "November" : { "Android" : 2, "ios" : 2, "blackberry" :
 1 } } } }
{ "value" : { "2014" : { "October" : { "Android" : 3, "ios" : 2 } } } }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks advanced for my begginer level and a bit hard for me to debug it :) I implemented it but it returns me this error: `Error: the out option parameter must be defined, see mongodb docs for possible values`. If you have a na idea please let me know how can I solve it.

Comment: @Webdesigner  No answer is advanced, its just that you might not know the concepts. It is really a great thing to learn new concepts and then picking up one for your use case becomes very easy.Have updated my answer with how to execute map reduce on mongoose in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using an output structure that's more natural for MongoDB where the keys are static and the values contain the data.  Then you can use an aggregation pipeline to do this as:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    // Group the docs by month & os
    {$group: {_id: {month: {$month: '$date'}, os: '$os'}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
    // Group again by just month
    {$group: {_id: '$_id.month', counts: {$push: {os: '$_id.os', count: '$count'}}}},
    // Rename _id to month
    {$project: {month: '$_id', counts: 1, _id: 0}}
], callback);
```

Which generates output like:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "counts" : [ 
                {
                    "os" : "winPhone",
                    "count" : 2
                }, 
                {
                    "os" : "iOS",
                    "count" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "os" : "Android",
                    "count" : 2
                }
            ],
            "month" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "counts" : [ 
                {
                    "os" : "iOS",
                    "count" : 2
                }, 
                {
                    "os" : "Android",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ],
            "month" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you really want the original format you can then post-process the result to reshape it however you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in your code, line 2 return `[ { counts: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],month: 11 } ]` and I can't find why.

Comment: Hi, I can't belive that I didn't see that the returned element is an array and now I can see the content asking the first element like result[0]. Thanks!